# Neo4j Cypher query fails and return with an Unknown Error

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to build a Cypher query to test if a specific structure exists so I can relate dates to it.

Running Neo4j 2.1.0-M01 on a Linux server, but the same issue occurred with Neo4j 2.0.1

We're starting with a clean database, 0 nodes.

First I'm running this MATCH query to prove that it runs. 
Obviously this query is not going to return any nodes. But after creating the nodes, it will 
fail with an 'unknown error'. 
It seems like a bug to me, since a query with fewer nodes will return. Does anyone have suggestions how to rewrite this query for now?

Sorry for the large amount of code in this post.

Thanks,

-Edwin

Cypher Query:

`MATCH (c:Cluster{cluster_name:'mycluster',cluster_uuid:'7bd4f66d-5faf-11db-8d0d-000e0cba569c'})
,(sc1:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610071',system_id:'1873784171',hostname:'node01',node_uuid:'7cd70205-66ae-11e0-a4a9-0deba859517d'})
,(sc1)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc2:Controller{serialnumber:'7000606111',system_id:'1873778118',hostname:'node02',node_uuid:'b954f0a1-6682-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc2)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc3:Controller{serialnumber:'7000561878',system_id:'1873772083',hostname:'node03',node_uuid:'ac293586-6690-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc3)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc4:Controller{serialnumber:'800000075807',system_id:'1873784143',hostname:'node04',node_uuid:'e8d6c7e5-663e-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc4)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc5:Controller{serialnumber:'7000477261',system_id:'1873745662',hostname:'node05',node_uuid:'1d1ecc64-728c-11e0-bf0e-3d25383f7ed3'})
,(sc5)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc6:Controller{serialnumber:'7000477273',system_id:'1873745654',hostname:'node06',node_uuid:'140fb0f9-728c-11e0-afeb-49fcf0b6e6c3'})
,(sc6)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc7:Controller{serialnumber:'7000474908',system_id:'1873745665',hostname:'node07',node_uuid:'edbf9c62-728b-11e0-bf0e-3d25383f7ed3'})
,(sc7)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc8:Controller{serialnumber:'7000474910',system_id:'1873745695',hostname:'node08',node_uuid:'20dbfe67-7832-11e0-afeb-49fcf0b6e6c3'})
,(sc8)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc9:Controller{serialnumber:'7000609864',system_id:'1873802756',hostname:'node09',node_uuid:'a8b75397-6690-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc9)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc10:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610021',system_id:'1873791030',hostname:'node10',node_uuid:'f6cf0705-6670-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc10)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc11:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610057',system_id:'1873784128',hostname:'node11',node_uuid:'551b1bf8-663d-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc11)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc12:Controller{serialnumber:'7000609981',system_id:'1873778164',hostname:'node12',node_uuid:'f6062d6c-663e-11e0-9b53-cd0ece6aa2ce'})
,(sc12)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc13:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610033',system_id:'1873778186',hostname:'node13',node_uuid:'ed0e61c5-6670-11e0-b07f-933da0385fdc'})
,(sc13)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc14:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610069',system_id:'1873784175',hostname:'node14',node_uuid:'8623ea28-66ae-11e0-ab9d-5fdc7f30dee7'})
,(sc14)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc15:Controller{serialnumber:'7000606109',system_id:'1873778197',hostname:'node15',node_uuid:'b4349a83-6682-11e0-ab9d-5fdc7f30dee7'})
,(sc15)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc16:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610045',system_id:'1873784157',hostname:'node16',node_uuid:'67d80db8-663d-11e0-9b53-cd0ece6aa2ce'})
,(sc16)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc17:Controller{serialnumber:'7001246085',system_id:'2014175904',hostname:'node19',node_uuid:'1c792588-ff4e-11db-94fe-3b91dd7dd242'})
,(sc17)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc18:Controller{serialnumber:'7001246097',system_id:'2014176797',hostname:'node20',node_uuid:'3ae9e7ae-ff44-11db-864d-af2af862bba3'})
,(sc18)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
RETURN c,sc1,sc2,sc3,sc4,sc5,sc6,sc7,sc8,sc9,sc10,sc11,sc12,sc13,sc14,sc15,sc16,sc17,sc18`

**Rows returned: 0**

Cypher Query for creating the nodes:

`CREATE (c:Cluster{cluster_name:'mycluster',cluster_uuid:'7bd4f66d-5faf-11db-8d0d-000e0cba569c'})
,(sc1:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610071',system_id:'1873784171',hostname:'node01',node_uuid:'7cd70205-66ae-11e0-a4a9-0deba859517d'})
,(sc1)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc2:Controller{serialnumber:'7000606111',system_id:'1873778118',hostname:'node02',node_uuid:'b954f0a1-6682-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc2)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc3:Controller{serialnumber:'7000561878',system_id:'1873772083',hostname:'node03',node_uuid:'ac293586-6690-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc3)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc4:Controller{serialnumber:'800000075807',system_id:'1873784143',hostname:'node04',node_uuid:'e8d6c7e5-663e-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc4)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc5:Controller{serialnumber:'7000477261',system_id:'1873745662',hostname:'node05',node_uuid:'1d1ecc64-728c-11e0-bf0e-3d25383f7ed3'})
,(sc5)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc6:Controller{serialnumber:'7000477273',system_id:'1873745654',hostname:'node06',node_uuid:'140fb0f9-728c-11e0-afeb-49fcf0b6e6c3'})
,(sc6)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc7:Controller{serialnumber:'7000474908',system_id:'1873745665',hostname:'node07',node_uuid:'edbf9c62-728b-11e0-bf0e-3d25383f7ed3'})
,(sc7)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc8:Controller{serialnumber:'7000474910',system_id:'1873745695',hostname:'node08',node_uuid:'20dbfe67-7832-11e0-afeb-49fcf0b6e6c3'})
,(sc8)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc9:Controller{serialnumber:'7000609864',system_id:'1873802756',hostname:'node09',node_uuid:'a8b75397-6690-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc9)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc10:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610021',system_id:'1873791030',hostname:'node10',node_uuid:'f6cf0705-6670-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc10)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc11:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610057',system_id:'1873784128',hostname:'node11',node_uuid:'551b1bf8-663d-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc11)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc12:Controller{serialnumber:'7000609981',system_id:'1873778164',hostname:'node12',node_uuid:'f6062d6c-663e-11e0-9b53-cd0ece6aa2ce'})
,(sc12)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc13:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610033',system_id:'1873778186',hostname:'node13',node_uuid:'ed0e61c5-6670-11e0-b07f-933da0385fdc'})
,(sc13)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc14:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610069',system_id:'1873784175',hostname:'node14',node_uuid:'8623ea28-66ae-11e0-ab9d-5fdc7f30dee7'})
,(sc14)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc15:Controller{serialnumber:'7000606109',system_id:'1873778197',hostname:'node15',node_uuid:'b4349a83-6682-11e0-ab9d-5fdc7f30dee7'})
,(sc15)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc16:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610045',system_id:'1873784157',hostname:'node16',node_uuid:'67d80db8-663d-11e0-9b53-cd0ece6aa2ce'})
,(sc16)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc17:Controller{serialnumber:'7001246085',system_id:'2014175904',hostname:'node19',node_uuid:'1c792588-ff4e-11db-94fe-3b91dd7dd242'})
,(sc17)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc18:Controller{serialnumber:'7001246097',system_id:'2014176797',hostname:'node20',node_uuid:'3ae9e7ae-ff44-11db-864d-af2af862bba3'})
,(sc18)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
RETURN c,sc1,sc2,sc3,sc4,sc5,sc6,sc7,sc8,sc9,sc10,sc11,sc12,sc13,sc14,sc15,sc16,sc17,sc18`

**19 nodes created, 18 relationships.**

Now when I run the first query again, it takes one minute  and will eventually return with 'Unknown error'.

Cypher Query:

`MATCH (c:Cluster{cluster_name:'mycluster',cluster_uuid:'7bd4f66d-5faf-11db-8d0d-000e0cba569c'})
,(sc1:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610071',system_id:'1873784171',hostname:'node01',node_uuid:'7cd70205-66ae-11e0-a4a9-0deba859517d'})
,(sc1)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc2:Controller{serialnumber:'7000606111',system_id:'1873778118',hostname:'node02',node_uuid:'b954f0a1-6682-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc2)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc3:Controller{serialnumber:'7000561878',system_id:'1873772083',hostname:'node03',node_uuid:'ac293586-6690-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc3)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc4:Controller{serialnumber:'800000075807',system_id:'1873784143',hostname:'node04',node_uuid:'e8d6c7e5-663e-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc4)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc5:Controller{serialnumber:'7000477261',system_id:'1873745662',hostname:'node05',node_uuid:'1d1ecc64-728c-11e0-bf0e-3d25383f7ed3'})
,(sc5)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc6:Controller{serialnumber:'7000477273',system_id:'1873745654',hostname:'node06',node_uuid:'140fb0f9-728c-11e0-afeb-49fcf0b6e6c3'})
,(sc6)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc7:Controller{serialnumber:'7000474908',system_id:'1873745665',hostname:'node07',node_uuid:'edbf9c62-728b-11e0-bf0e-3d25383f7ed3'})
,(sc7)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc8:Controller{serialnumber:'7000474910',system_id:'1873745695',hostname:'node08',node_uuid:'20dbfe67-7832-11e0-afeb-49fcf0b6e6c3'})
,(sc8)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc9:Controller{serialnumber:'7000609864',system_id:'1873802756',hostname:'node09',node_uuid:'a8b75397-6690-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc9)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc10:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610021',system_id:'1873791030',hostname:'node10',node_uuid:'f6cf0705-6670-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc10)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc11:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610057',system_id:'1873784128',hostname:'node11',node_uuid:'551b1bf8-663d-11e0-b8a0-517da924923d'})
,(sc11)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc12:Controller{serialnumber:'7000609981',system_id:'1873778164',hostname:'node12',node_uuid:'f6062d6c-663e-11e0-9b53-cd0ece6aa2ce'})
,(sc12)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc13:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610033',system_id:'1873778186',hostname:'node13',node_uuid:'ed0e61c5-6670-11e0-b07f-933da0385fdc'})
,(sc13)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc14:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610069',system_id:'1873784175',hostname:'node14',node_uuid:'8623ea28-66ae-11e0-ab9d-5fdc7f30dee7'})
,(sc14)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc15:Controller{serialnumber:'7000606109',system_id:'1873778197',hostname:'node15',node_uuid:'b4349a83-6682-11e0-ab9d-5fdc7f30dee7'})
,(sc15)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc16:Controller{serialnumber:'7000610045',system_id:'1873784157',hostname:'node16',node_uuid:'67d80db8-663d-11e0-9b53-cd0ece6aa2ce'})
,(sc16)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc17:Controller{serialnumber:'7001246085',system_id:'2014175904',hostname:'node19',node_uuid:'1c792588-ff4e-11db-94fe-3b91dd7dd242'})
,(sc17)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
,(sc18:Controller{serialnumber:'7001246097',system_id:'2014176797',hostname:'node20',node_uuid:'3ae9e7ae-ff44-11db-864d-af2af862bba3'})
,(sc18)-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]->(c)
RETURN c,sc1,sc2,sc3,sc4,sc5,sc6,sc7,sc8,sc9,sc10,sc11,sc12,sc13,sc14,sc15,sc16,sc17,sc18`

**Returns `Unknown Error`**

Answer (score 1):

Your MATCH query is way to complicated. There's no need to specify every node. The following query returns the cluster and its related controllers:

```
MATCH (c:Cluster{cluster_name:'mycluster',cluster_uuid:'7bd4f66d-5faf-11db-8d0d-000e0cba569c'})<-[:IS_PART_OF_CLUSTER]-(sc:Controller) 
WITH c, collect(sc) as controllers 
RETURN c as cluster, controllers
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is indeed a complex query. But it is needed since we need to test if this specific cluster with all these controllers already exists. If the cluster exists already, then we will update the 'last' or 'first' reported dates, if needed, pointint to the cluster node. If this specific cluster config doesn't exist yet, then we will create it with a start and end date.